# How to Push Videos from a Mac app to Iphone?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, electron

I have a problem I need to solve. I am planning on building a desktop app(Mac and Windows both).

The Problem is that I need to transfer the video from the Desktop App to iPhone(while iPhone is connected through USB). Any Idea how that can be done?

Comment: I would use electron and react or angular for the app itself. For the io call (push file) you can use the electron dialog project: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md . Since your OS knows your connected phone, the dialog will show you the location.

Comment: Thanks @baerree That is helpful :)
Any examples related to the dialog.md project you know of?

Comment: there is example code on the repo. Just try it.